# Connect multiple MPPT charge controllers to a single solar panel?

Tags: solar-cell, solar-energy, solar-charge-controller

I have a small 18V/80W solar panel and some old lead-acid UPS batteries (that I got for free). About half of them are one brand and the other half are another, so I don't want to connect them all in parallel.

Is it possible to connect multiple MPPT charge controllers to the one solar panel? My understanding is that MPPT charge controllers try provide the optimal amount of load to get the maximum power from the panel, so I'm not sure if connecting multiple chargers to the same panel might result in the chargers essentially "fighting" each other, and if there's any delay in the chargers deciding the best load they might end up oscillating back and forth.

My understanding of MPPT controllers might be completely wrong, though.

Comment: if each battery is to be charged at the correct rate, how many can you charge at one time?

Comment: @SolarMike I'm not sure what you mean. That sounds like the kind of question I used to get in my schoolwork haha.

Comment: I believe Solar Mike is implying to connect them in series. I could be wrong of course!

Comment: @Andyaka But I don't want and can't used a 24V system. That seems like an odd suggestion.

Comment: And you can't have MPPT circuits fighting each other so, does it get you closer to what you want if you have one MPPT circuit feeding a bunch of series batteries OR a non-working system using multiple MPPTs in parallel? Of course @SolarMike may have had a different idea entirely.

Comment: @Andyaka well, I was just starting form the available power and what batteries in parallel might need at the correct rates even before considering MPPT...

Comment: @Andyaka Wait, so the MPPT circuits _would_ fight each other? That was one of my questions.

Comment: Yes it was and it was a good question; they will fight hence, use one MPPT and have the batteries in series (if they all appear good) and then down-convert using a buck regulator to the required voltage. That's what I'd be thinking along the lines of.

Comment: @SolarMike What do you mean by "correct rates"? Surely there's no such thing as "correct" rates, only "acceptable" rates. You can charge as slow as you want, the only limit is not charging too fast. Are you asking if the panel/charger can charge fast enough (in which case, fast enough for what? For me to consider it acceptable?) or if the panel/charger will charge too fast (it won't)?

Comment: @Andyaka Surely different capacities in series is a bad idea, though. I would imagine that the lower-capacity batteries would discharge first and reach a lower voltage earlier, which would (I think) cause the larger battery to begin charging the smaller battery through the load, but backwards. Obviously no packs have identical capacities and internal resistances, so there's clearly some leeway. But given they're different brands and I don't even know the nominal capacities (they don't say) I don't think it would be a good idea to connect them directly at all.

Comment: Why didn't you mention this in the question dude? What's the point of mentioning that half were one brand and half were another if none or few are the same rating? What was that about?

Comment: @Andyaka What? I'm saying that I've got 7 of one brand (all from the same UPS) and 8 of another brand (all from a different UPS). Within each brand they're all identical, as far as I can tell. My point about connecting those two groups in series is that it could be potentially bad, as I understand it.

Comment: @Clonkex - did you get an answer on this? I have the same situation. 3 batteries and only space for 1 solar pane. Thanks Rob